# How will i create a link in my menu that point to that same page

Tags: html

How will i create a link in my menu that point to that same page . like what happend in this site http://nightswatch.afrcreative.com/ the about us is still in the same page not another page

Answer (score 0):

This is acheived using anchor tags.

Refer [here](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use anchor tags like so:

```css
.tall {
 height: 600px;
 background: cyan;
 }
 
 .about {
  height: 500px;
  
 }
```

```html
<div class="tall">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
<div class="about">
  <a name="about" />
  <h1>About</h1>
</div>
```

You can then get fancy and intercept this with js to smoothly animate or use the `scroll-behavior` css property.